# Foundation for apps animation with custom controller

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

```
---
name: about
url: /about
controller: AboutCtrl
animationIn: slideInDown
---
```

animation doesn't work, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding animationOut?
For example:

```
---
name: about
url: /about
controller: AboutCtrl
animationIn: slideInDown
animationOut: fadeOut
---
```